# C# WCF - Failed to invoke the service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting the following error when trying to use the WCF Test Client to hit my new web service.  What is weird is every once in awhile it will execute once then start popping this error.

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

My code (interface):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://rivworks.com/Services/2010/04/19")]
public interface ISync
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Execute(long ClientID);
}
```

My code (class):

```
public class Sync : ISync
{
    #region ISync Members
    bool ISync.Execute(long ClientID)
    {
        return model.Product(ClientID);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My config (EDIT - posted entire serviceModel section):

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default">
    <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
  </diagnostics>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonpServiceBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" policyVersion="Policy15"/>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="RivWorks.Web.Service.ServiceBehavior">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <services>
    <service name="RivWorks.Web.Service.NegotiateService" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="JsonpServiceBehavior"
                contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.NegotiateService" />
      <!--<host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://kab.rivworks.com/services"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.NegotiateService" />-->
      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpBinding"
                contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.NegotiateService" />
    </service>
    <service name="RivWorks.Web.Service.Sync" behaviorConfiguration="RivWorks.Web.Service.ServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="RivWorks.Web.Service.ISync" />
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <extensions>
    <bindingElementExtensions>
      <add name="jsonpMessageEncoding" type="RivWorks.Web.Service.JSONPBindingExtension, RivWorks.Web.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </bindingElementExtensions>
  </extensions>

  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="jsonpBinding" >
        <jsonpMessageEncoding />
        <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>    
</system.serviceModel>
```

2 questions:

1. What am I missing that causes this error?
2. How can I increase the time out for the service?

TIA!

Comment: @Petoj: It means "Thanks in advance"

Comment: Can you repost your config file?  Under <services> there are two closing </service> tags but only one opening <service> tag.  I can't tell whether you just snipped the relevant service or if it's indeed messed up.

Comment: Also, where are you defining RivWorks.Web.Service.ServiceBehavior?

Comment: Local web server or a web farm, or a web garden? Also, kind of looks like you're using LINQ to SQL, is that true? (If not, what ORM are you using?)

Comment: I am using LINQ to SQL.  Found the problem.  (1) The test app does not abort the channel if an error is thrown which locks the channel.  (2) There was a problem deep in the Sync routine that was database driven.  Added try/catch around the whole sync process and kept drilling into the InnerException to find it.  Once I had the try/catch in place (graceful failure) the channel no longer locks up.

Comment: Singular web server, hosted server for now.  I also added the entire serviceModel section as I do have a JSONP based web service also running - and it still works.  (See above comment from me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem(s)...

1. Had an error inside the web service that was not handled.
2. The test app does not do an ABORT when it sees an error.  Instead, it is left unhandled (and unreported) **AND** the channel is now locked because of the error.

Putting a try/catch around the inside method makes it so I can log the error **and** the test app does not lock up.