# silverlight datagrid not showing data

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have silverlight application with a WCF service to access a table in sql server DB. I copied all the code from the tutorial and running it from my desktop. It failes to load the sql server data although everything else loads fine.
Other posts talk about the http://localhost:PortNumber/Service1.svc being the problem and I should deploy the servive while others talk about using an observable collection instead. Does anyone have an explanation on what the issue could be and how to correct it.

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
```

Public Class Service1

```
<OperationContract()>
Public Function GetPostCounts() As List(Of RealTimePostCount)
    ' Add your operation implementation here
    Dim db As New DataClasses1DataContext

    Dim posts = (From record In db.RealTimePostCounts Order By record.boxCount, record.boxFeed, record.pollDate Select record)
    Dim list As New List(Of RealTimePostCount)
    For Each p In posts
        list.Add(New RealTimePostCount With {.boxCount = p.boxCount, .boxFeed = p.boxFeed, .pollDate = p.pollDate})
    Next

    Return list


End Function

' Add more operations here and mark them with <OperationContract()>
```

End Class

servicerefernces..clientconfig

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:12018/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_Service1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down the problem into smaller chunks.

- Eliminate WCF from the equation to verify that your Silverlight databinding is working correctly. You can do this by simply binding to a premade list.
- The [WcfTestClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) allows you to isolate and test your web service independent of Silverlight.
- When troubleshooting Silverlight and WCF together, [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a must so that you can see your applications service call and the response.

Hopefully this is enough to solve or lead you to a more specific problem.

Comment: got the following error with testclient :  Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Comment: now you have a more detailed error. try starting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671113/c-wcf-failed-to-invoke-the-service