# WCF service failing on executing an operation that returns custom type (DataContract)

Tags: wcf

I have a data contract which is marked as `Serializable` in web.config.
A WCF operation is written to return this data contract to the calling method.
But I am receiving following error:

> The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration
>   does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the
>   stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new
>   proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

While trying to execute the operation. Though it reaches till execution of last line, and then gets failed.
I am using BasicHttpBinding

Comment: Take a look.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671113/c-sharp-wcf-failed-to-invoke-the-service

Comment: didn't help... in my case, its failing for particular data contract